# PHPExcel - PDF convert doesn't work

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to open .xls file, edit it via PHPExcel and save as .pdf. I have got this source code:

```
<?php   
set_include_path('Classes/');
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('document.xls');
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'řčřč');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'B');
$sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'C');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('document.pdf');
?>
```

But it gives me this error

> Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'PDF
>   Rendering library has not been defined.' in
>   /data/web/virtuals/55146/virtual/www/faktury/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF.php:56
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /data/web/virtuals/55146/virtual/www/faktury/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(141):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_PDF->__construct(Object(PHPExcel)) #1
>   /data/web/virtuals/55146/virtual/www/faktury/faktura.php(29):
>   PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter(Object(PHPExcel), 'PDF') #2 {main}
>   thrown in
>   /data/web/virtuals/55146/virtual/www/faktury/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF.php
>   on line 56

My PHP program is located in the same folder as Classes folder.

Have you got someone any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So define the detail for the 3rd party rendering library that you're using for your application - PHPExcel allows you a choice of working with DomPDF, TcPDF or mPDF, but you need to tell PHPExcel which of those three you have installed; and it is also [documented](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md) as well as showing examples in the /Examples folder

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel allows you a choice of working with DomPDF, TcPDF or mPDF, but you need to tell PHPExcel which of those three you have installed.

Simply setting a few variables in your script won't help (as you've subsequently done), you need to **tell** PHPExcel to use DomPDF and where the DomPDF library is located in your system

```
<?php   
set_include_path('Classes/');
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'domPDF0.6.0beta3';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__). 'libs/classes/dompdf' . $rendererLibrary;

//  Here's the magic: you __tell__ PHPExcel what rendering engine to use
//     and where the library is located in your filesystem
if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
    $rendererName,
    $rendererLibraryPath
)) {
    die('NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
}

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('document.xls');
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'řčřč');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'B');
$sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'C');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('document.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: But where can I find domPDF library? The path should be something like  libs/classes/dompdf/domPDF0.6.0beta3 but on domPDF github there https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf is totally different structure.